# How to enter data in a dlookup field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Probably I'm not wording my problem in Google properly but I have a form that uses a query as the source and one of the field (Price) is a dlookup formula. The problem I am having is that some products do not have a fixed price, so I need a method to manually enter the price in the text box anytime those products are selected. On the same form there is a Quantity text box, once it is clicked a pop-up is triggered and the user can change the amounts if I get something along that lines when the Price field is clicked a pop-up is displayed for the user to enter the price.

Comment: You can't. A field bound to an expression is always read-only. So, you must find another approach.

Comment: Any advice on how to manually enter the price? Even if it means that I need to redesign the form.

Comment: You could remove the DLookup from the query. Then lookup the price in the form and set the price, if any, as the DefaultValue of the textbox where the user will enter the price.

Comment: User selects product from combobox. Price is a column in combobox. VBA code in combobox AfterUpdate event references column of combobox: `If IsNull(Me!Price) Then Me!Price = comboboxname.Column(2)`. User can type over. Why bother with popups?

Comment: No, Price is not a column in the Product combobox. I have a separate table for the prices because Prices change. That is why I am using a dlookup, it finds the current price for a product based on the date.